# How to remove first 5 and last 3 characters from a NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring

For example my string is `NSString *str=@"appleIsTheBest"`. Remember that the code have to work with any strings, not just with this.

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *str = @"appleIsTheBest";
str = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(5, str.length - 5 - 3)];
```

Of course, you'll need to check the string's length before sending the `substringWithRange:` message.